# iOS: get View size during initialization

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiview, size

in an `iOS` `OpenGL` app i'd like to get the width and height of a `GLKView`.  It seems the size of the view is (0, 0) in `viewDidLoad` and other callbacks.

Basically the size of the `GLKView` i use is fixed but for `Retina-/Non-Retina-Devices` the actual dimensions differ and i'd like to also handle possible future devices.

Googling, it looks to me that the size is not fixed during initialization yet.  But detecting the size of a view during initialization seems to be a standard problem, i wonder how this is normally handled?  Is there a way to detect the size once or do i (for example) need to detect the size each time in `drawInRect()` and re-initialize when a change is detected?

Thanks for any hints,
Torsten.

Answer (score 1):

> But detecting the size of a view during initialization seems to be a standard problem, i wonder how this is normally handled?

It is usually not handled at initialization, but later when the view is about to be rendered. In the `viewWillAppear:` callback, for instance. Check if you can postpone your GL initialization until then.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.  In the code i take the view and cast it to GLKView* (which it is).  I can then access view.frame.size or view.drawableWidth / view.drawableHeight.  view.frame.size gives me an incorrect value when i'm in the simulator and setting a Retina device.  But the incorrect value is available at viewDidLoad: already.  view.drawableWidth gives the correct value but is only available from viewDidAppear: onwards.  This does not really help much.

Comment: Basically all i want are the correct dimensions in a callback that is called once (before displaying the view) to initialize my own data (once).

Comment: Well, I told you what is this callback: it is viewWillAppear. Actually, read the UiViewController doc, and you'll see that's there is not much other candidate. Now since you still have some issue, I guess it's time to look after some other wrong assumption of yours. Eventually you'll come up with some clean and simple code. Good luck.

Comment: @GwendalRoué The other candidate (for iOS 5 and later) is [`viewWillLayoutSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews).